# How to deal with the LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES in android .mk

Tags: android, android-ndk, native-activity, vs-android

I'm trying to port one of the android NDK samples (native-activity) to work with the vs-android plugging that lets me develop in MVS.

To do this I need to translate the Android.mk commands into something MVS can deal with, and I'm having trouble with one of them.

Android.mk :
    LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := native-activity
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := main.c
LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -llog -landroid -lEGL -lGLESv1_CM
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := android_native_app_glue

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

$(call import-module,android/native_app_glue)
```

The lines of LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES  and $(call import-module,android/native_app_glue) obviously deal with the native_app_glue that is central to making the native_activity class do it's magic.

Any idea on how to translate this in terms of compile line options in vs-android, linker options of MVS or anything similar? Or at least what those two lines do?

Cheers,
Jaime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it to work.

As it seems to be creating a library (native_app_glue) from what the .mk says, I went ahead and compiled the native_app_glue library as another static library (.a) project in my MVS, and then added it to the project dependencies. This worked with no problems